# iOS Static library - If a public header imports private headers, do those headers also become public?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I'm building a static library for iOS using Xcode. If I have a public header file, that imports a bunch of private header files, do those header files become public? Or would also have to make these header files public so they can be accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, otherwise it will not compile.

Before your code is going to be compiled, preprocessor replaces `#include ...` statement with content of respective header file. If preprocessor can't do it, it will fail.

In other words, you must have all header files, and all header files used in header files, ... accessible.

Create .c / .m file, include your header file you would like to make public and select *Product - Perform Action - Preprocess "..."* to see what happens. This is what will be compiled.